# How do I fix missing application icons in the Static Application Switcher option provided by ccsm?

Tags: unity, compiz, icons, application-switcher, ccsm

I use the static application switcher provided by compiz config settings manager (ccsm) but a few programs do not have icons when in window preview mode. I have tried putting icons in various places that they are often stored (e.g. `/usr/share/icons`), but I can't seem to find the location that the ccsm switcher sources from. And, yes, I have named the icon as it is called in the *.desktop file.

[image: Static application switcher showing eclipse preview with missing icon]

Comment: It's a confirmed defect: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/1088178

Comment: Yeah, I am the Ben you posted under in that bug report.